# subset sum with memoization

Tags: python, recursion, sum, subset, memoization

for homework, i wrote a recursive function for subset sum, but i can't find the right key for my dictionary, i keep getting key errors all the time.
not looking for the solution, just explanations that can help me understand what is worng:

```
def subset_sum(s, numbers):
    memo={}
    return subset_sum_memo(s, numbers, 1, memo)

def subset_sum_memo(s, numbers, i, memo):
    key= (len(numbers))
    if key not in memo:
        if s==0:
            memo[key]= True
        elif s<0 or numbers==[]:
            memo[key]= False
        for n in range(len(numbers)):
            if subset_sum_memo(s - numbers[n], numbers[:n] + numbers[n+1:], n, memo):
                memo[key]= True
    return memo[key]
```

error i am getting is:

```
if subset_sum_memo(s - numbers[n], numbers[:n] + numbers[n+1:], n, memo): 
File "C:\Users\Yarden\Desktop\Python\302154513_ex11_q1.py", line 17, in subset_sum_memo return memo[key] KeyError: 6
```

**Update 1**

This is my new code:

```
def subset_sum(s, numbers):
    memo={}
    return subset_sum_memo(s, numbers, 1, memo)


def subset_sum_memo(s, numbers, i, memo):
    key= (len(numbers))
    if s==0:
        memo[key]= True
    if s<0 or numbers==[]:
        memo[key]= False
    if key not in memo:
        for n in range(len(numbers)):
            if subset_sum_memo(s - numbers[n], numbers[:n] + numbers[n+1:], n, memo):
                memo[key]= True
            else:
                memo[key]=False
    return memo[key]
```

Still have problems, can't figure out why

Comment: What do the errors say? Can you post them?

Comment: if subset_sum_memo(s - numbers[n], numbers[:n] + numbers[n+1:], n, memo):
  File "C:\Users\Yarden\Desktop\Python\302154513_ex11_q1.py", line 17, in subset_sum_memo
    return memo[key]
KeyError: 6

Comment: There are times in your for-loop that `memo[key]` is not set because it is bounded by an if-statement.  In those cases you get a KeyError when trying to access `memo[key]` in the return statement.

Comment: BTW, memoization in Python calls for a decorator. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578231-probably-the-fastest-memoization-decorator-in-the-/

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
if key not in memo:
    if s==0:
        memo[key]= True
    elif s<0 or numbers==[]:
        memo[key]= False
    for n in range(len(numbers)):
        if subset_sum_memo(s - numbers[n], numbers[:n] + numbers[n+1:], n, memo):
            memo[key]= True
return memo[key]
```

The problem is, you are checking whether `key` is not in `memo` and entering the block. Then you are having multiple conditionals but not a default case.

What if all the conditionals are `false`, then the value won't be set for `memo[key]`.

Comment: I think i understnd, I took the conditions out of "if key is not..." but still got the same error.

Comment: You have to make sure that `memo[key]` is set before the function returns.

Comment: also added "else: memo[key]=False", still getting different errors on my doctest: TEST: s = 64  and numbers = [23, 40, 20, 6, 3, 12, 20, 21, 18, 17] :  FAILURE
    Expected True and got False

Comment: To program right you have to think right, separate responsibilities, for number in list, if number in cache then return, if not then calculate and add to cache. That's it.

Comment: def subset_sum(s, numbers):
    memo={}
    return subset_sum_memo(s, numbers, 1, memo)
    

def subset_sum_memo(s, numbers, i, memo):
    key= (len(numbers))
    if s==0:
        memo[key]= True
    if s<0 or numbers==[]:
        memo[key]= False
    if key not in memo:
        for n in range(len(numbers)):
            if subset_sum_memo(s - numbers[n], numbers[:n] + numbers[n+1:], n, memo):
                memo[key]= True
            else:
                memo[key]=False
    return memo[key]

Comment: thr for loop goes through the list and calls the function again as if the first number is chosen etc

Comment: You should print the variables inside the loop to see what values are being passed around. This is an issue with the logic rather than the language. Do you want a solution?

Answer (score 0):

change `elif s<0 or numbers==[]:` to 
`elif s<0 or isinstance(numbers,list):`